# Stripes Layout with Validation

Tags: validation, layout, stripes

I try to use the Stripes layout tags (layout-definition, layout-render, ...).
My layout include a header with a menu and a content under.
I render a form with Stripes validation in the content :

```
    @ValidateNestedProperties({
    @Validate(field="email", required=true, on="edit", converter=EmailTypeConverter.class), ...
```

If I use the validation I get an exception :

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1232: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20
```

If I remove the validation of the form, it works...

Any idea how to be able to use both? Or probably I am doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please post additional code for your layout. I do not believe this error has anything to do with your validation.

It could sound like you are calling jsp includes over and over again. e.g.:

a.jsp includes b.jsp which includes a.jsp etc...